# How to install Debian Testing

Tags: linux, debian, linux-distributions

I would like to install debian testing.

I mean that I want to follow the "Testing" distribution.

I have tried the installer included in unetbootin "Ubuntu_Testing_Netinst". Once it installed, it was following the "Squeeze" Distro.

Where can I find a net installer that will follow "Testing"?

Answer (score 3):

Grab a non-gui Debian squeeze install go into expert mode, one on the options will be to select an alternate release.

Or, if you have fast network access and a supported interface grab a mini.iso.

- http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso
- http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Or, install squeeze, update your sources and dist-upgrade.